# Retrieve Arraylist from session

Tags: java, session, arraylist

```
 Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

I am using this session to store an ArrayList in session. The type given below.

```
ArrayList<Object> temp2 =  new ArrayList<Object>();
```

like this

```
RulesDTO dto = new RulesDTO();

//objective number = 15 and value=56

dto.seteNumber(objectiveValue);
dto.setValue(Double.parseDouble(formBean.getNumber().toString()));

session.put("1", dto);
temp2.add(session.get("1"));
```

now i want to `System.out` these values. of `temp2` which is got from session
Could anybody suggest any code.

Comment: You have put only one object to the session. The code is impossible to get if you don't understand the topic.

Comment: No i want to insert more object to the session

Comment: What you want is different from what you've shown us. Your question is impossible to understand as it is now... please take the time to edit it and make it answerable, if you want to get help

Comment: @HarshitWadhera Generally speaking I could tell you how to insert more objects but I'm not sure you get it. If you wanna use a collection like a map or list nothing prevents you to insert any number of objects without a limitation on the size. The collection grows smoothly toward the memory footprint giving you an ability to use a collection's api.

Comment: @RomanC Please let me know to insert more objects and get it from session.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, could you edit the question and highlight what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solve your problem is to always store your Session and get your Session using the same key.

Initialization

```
ArrayList<Object> temp2 =  new ArrayList<Object>();
session.set("<YOUR_KEY>",temp2);
```

To add a new object, retrieve the ArrayList from the Session first and then add into the ArrayList. Don't forget to set the ArrayList back to the Session.

```
ArrayList<Object> fromSession = session.get("<YOUR_KEY>");
fromSession.add("test");
fromSession.add("test2");
session.set("<YOUR_KEY>",fromSession);
```

To print all object

```
ArrayList<Object> fromSession = session.get("<YOUR_KEY>");
for(Object obj : fromSession)
{ System.out.println(obj); }
```